# Get file status on mac drive with linux in C

Tags: c

I really need to ask a question for the first time.

I'm using C to get the modification time of a file in linux, which works fine:

```
struct stat st;
if(stat(path,&st)==0){
    printf("%ld\n", st.st_mtime);
}else{
    // HANDLE ERROR
}
```

But if I try to get the modification time on a timecapsule connected to my linux computer via network, I'm getting an error.

Thanks for every advice.

EDIT:
strace gives me following:

```
getcwd("/home/harry/capsule", 4096)     = 20
lstat64("/home/harry/capsule/.com.apple.timemachine.supported", {st_dev=makedev(0, 27), st_ino=184726543400980, st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=0, st_blksize=16384, st_blocks=0, st_size=0, st_atime=2016/04/03-19:38:54, st_mtime=2015/06/02-16:27:30, st_ctime=2015/06/02-16:27:30}) = 0
fstat64(1, {st_dev=makedev(0, 13), st_ino=6, st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=5, st_blksize=1024, st_blocks=0, st_rdev=makedev(136, 3), st_atime=2016/05/11-19:58:33, st_mtime=2016/05/11-19:58:33, st_ctime=2016/05/11-15:43:17}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb77d1000
write(1, "1 D: /home/harry/capsule/.com.ap"..., 581 D: /home/harry/capsule/.com.apple.timemachine.supported
) = 58
stat64("/home/harry/capsule/.com.apple.timemachine.supported", {st_dev=makedev(0, 27), st_ino=184726543400980, st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=0, st_blksize=16384, st_blocks=0, st_size=0, st_atime=2016/04/03-19:38:54, st_mtime=2015/06/02-16:27:30, st_ctime=2015/06/02-16:27:30}) = 0
```

Comment: Try `strace` or at least do `perror("stat")` instead of your `HANDLE ERROR` placeholder to determine which error you are hitting

Comment: @Harry : Which error do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it!
Just put `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` in the header of your code.